# On-Premise data gateway to SQL Server, database name has period

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi, data-gateway

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database with the On-Premise Data Gateway, but unfortunately I have a period in the name of the database (yes, I know it's a bad idea).  The gateway will successfully connect to databases without a period in the name, but I can't escape the name.

For instance:

Database name: Foo.Fighters
I've tried [Foo.Fighters] and "Foo.Fighters" in the Database field with not luck.

As soon as I change it to a different DB on that same server, we're all good.

Any thoughts that aren't, change the name of the DB?

Comment: I believe there's something called database synonyms for this in SQL Server.

Comment: That's a really good thought, I just confirmed that synonyms are only for specific objects.  For example, tables, stored procedures, etc.

Comment: Can you use SMSS to connect to Foo..., from its dropdown?  Is there a subtle spelling difference?  When using SQL what is the error message? Server version year?

Comment: Look at the error messages here, and the logging capabilities...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem-tshoot

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I can connect via SSMS, but not with the Add A Data Source button in PowerBI.  As soon as I change the name of the database to something the doesn't have a period in it, it works, but that's not helpful when I need to connect to [Foo.Fighters]

Comment: Try opening an issue here, hopefully it will signal the Power BI product group - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%2212a87ce1-0e1b-f21c-bad3-09963e628d99%22&in=body. Looks like a bug to me so it should be fixed upstream.